# Ajax error while connecting to external URL from mvc application

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to access external URL from my MVC application. Below jquery code is used for connecting to bbc.co.uk. But i am getting error jqXHR.status == 0

```
$("#Contactname").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "html",
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://news.bbc.co.uk",
            success: function (result) {
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                AjaxError(jqXHR, exception, "#Contenet");
                alert(2);
            }
        });
    });
```

Can some body show me why i am getting status=0 error.

Comment: Check here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Comment: I feel the same issue here for me. But couldnt get a solution